# Node EADDRINUSE on AWS regardless of port

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, nginx, amazon-ec2, port

I'm getting so frustrated... I can't find any information online to help me.

My setup is:

- AWS EC2 instance
- Nginx pointing to 127.0.0.1:3000
- Node JS v0.10.32
- mongoDB process running as daemon

I've tried using my public DNS/public IP and restarting nginx, I've tried port 80, 8000, 1337, etc... I've tried deleting Nginx. `ps aux | grep :3000` returns nothing. `ps aux | grep :80` returns nothing. etc...

**Here's the relevant code:**

```
https.createServer(options, app).listen(app.get('port'), '127.0.0.1', function() {
    console.log('Express server listening on port ' + app.get('port'));
});
http.createServer(function(req, res) {
    res.writeHead(301, { "Location": "https://" + req.headers['host'] + req.url });
  res.end();
}).listen(3000);
```

**No matter which port I use, I get the same error for `sudo node app.js` and `node app.js`:**

```
events.js:72
        throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
              ^
Error: listen EADDRINUSE
    at errnoException (net.js:904:11)
    at Server._listen2 (net.js:1042:14)
    at listen (net.js:1064:10)
    at net.js:1146:9
    at dns.js:72:18
    at process._tickCallback (node.js:419:13)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:499:11)
    at startup (node.js:119:16)
    at node.js:906:3
```

---

**I did get this to work, but I need to redirect traffic to port 443 and use https:**

```
app.listen(3000, '127.0.0.1', function() {
    console.log('Express server listening on port ' + app.get('port'));
});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `netstat -tulpn | grep :XX` , XX being the port you want to check.

It seems that you're trying to start both a http and a https server on the same port. delete the http.createServer bit and you'll be fine.

Comment: forgot to mention that I'm using this :`app.set('port', process.env.PORT || 443);`

Comment: the app wont launch, that's the problem.

Comment: Deleting the http.createServer part got the app to start, but I still can't seem to access it in a browser.

Answer (score 0):

According to my own experience (not on EC2) and also according to [this comment by the OP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26229640/node-eaddrinuse-on-aws-regardless-of-port?rq=1#comment41141584_26229832), I would bet that the solution to this problem is to run the process as `sudo` -- or, if you want, there must be a Linux group and permissions somewhere that prevents non-group users to attach processes to port 80 or 443, in which case running the process as a super user will do the job.

The fact that the OP delegated the job of attaching to the correct port to Nginx, and that Nginx is normally run as a super user process fits with this explanation.